# Can firefox use themes across the whole of 4096 pixels width?

Tags: firefox, appearance

I have a monitor with 4096x2160 pixels and run firefox at full width.

When I select a theme that comes with an image, it looks as if the image is at most 3000 pixels wide. About 1000 pixels (1/4th screen width) to the left are not used and this looks quite ugly, especially when the theme's default background color is different from the image's left edge color.

Is there a way to make firefox use wider images in themes?
One way I found is to cheat by changing the value of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` in `about:config` but that opens another can of worms.

For example, can I hack `userChrome.css` so the image is repeated horizontally?

Comment: You just have to find a larger image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about Firefox, not Unix & Linux, and may be better on another StackExchange site, such as SuperUser.